# Testing Phoenix.Controller.redirect

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm new to Phoenix and I'm testing a custom Plug that should redirect to the /404.html page if a condition is not met. The code works correctly when I try the success/failure paths but I'm having a difficult time understanding why my testing approach is blowing up.

The test failure boils down to the following:

```
%Plug.Conn{} |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: "/404.html")
```

My expectation is that this should return a `conn` object which I can then run assertions on. However, when I try to run the above code I get the following error:

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Conn.send_resp/4 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:
```

This is a bit weird since the Phoenix.Controller module implements a `send_resp/4` function and it imports the Plug.Conn at the top of its definition.

Why is it ignoring that function and trying to hit `Plug.Conn` directly? I'm not calling that private function, a public function is delegating to it, which should be kosher unless I've missed something obvious. Is there an easy solution to this problem or should I take another approach?

**EDIT**

Here is the full stack trace from iex:

```
%Plug.Conn{} |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: "/404.html")

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Conn.send_resp/4 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

  * send_resp/1
  * send_resp/3

(plug) Plug.Conn.send_resp(nil, 302, [{"content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"}, {"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, {"location", "/404.html"}], "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"/404.html\">redirected</a>.</body></html>")
(plug) lib/plug/conn.ex:393: Plug.Conn.send_resp/1
```

The `redirect` function's implementation can be found here: 
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.3/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L297

The `send_resp` function I expect it to hit can be found here:
https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.3/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L748

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of that error and the code around the line it refers to?

Comment: edited the post to include the stack trace

Comment: I think you need to use `Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn()` instead of `%Plug.Conn{}` for testing.

Comment: This works, however I still quite don't understand why using Plug.Conn directly does not work. I will dig in deeper and see what is going on.

Comment: Also, if it helps, you can use the [redirected_to/2 helper](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#redirected_to/2).

Answer (score 0):

As the first line of your Stacktrace indicates. `nil` is the first argument to the `Plug.Conn.send_resp/4` function. The `Plug.Conn.send_resp/4` function does not exist though. Only arity one and three as you can see in [the docs](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_resp/3) of in the [code](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.7.0/lib/plug/conn.ex#L554).

What you probably mixed it up with is the `Phoenix.Controller.send_resp/4` function as you linked it.

**Nontheless the main issue is, that `nil` is passed to the `send_resp` function which would not work for either function. It seems the conn was lost somewhere.**

Thus I suggest to go with @Dogbert's comment and use `Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn()` to mock a conn instead of initializing an empty conn struct with `%Plug.Conn{}`.